# Rails 4 / Koala: how to refresh long access token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Using Rails 4 and Koala gem version 2.
I have my personal Facebook **page** (not profile).
When I am publishing a new post in **my** website I want to automatically publish it on **my** facebook page as well. 
I am using Koala gem but I have some problem with access tokens.

Visiting  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ I get a **short-live** token. This token expires after only 2 hours.

My goal is to obtain a **long-live** token.
I have created a new Facebook app and I have obtained a **client-id** and **client-secret**.

Visiting this https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID&client_secret=MY-CLIENT-SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=MY-SHORT-LIVE-TOKEN I get **long-live** token.

Now I can use my long-live token to publish on my page:

```
user = Koala::Facebook::API.new long_live_access_token
page_access_token = user.get_connections('me', 'accounts').first['access_token']
page = Koala::Facebook::API.new page_access_token
page.put_connections("me", "feed", message: "I am posting on my page!ok!")
```

It seems to work, but my problems is that the long-live token expires in 60 days so I need to refresh it. 
I have found no solution to refresh a long-live token. It is clear that I can't repeat the entire procedure every 60 days!

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs:

> These tokens (*long-lived*) will be refreshed once per day when the
>   person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers. If no
>   requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and the
>   person will have to go through the login flow again to get a new
>   token.

The token that never expires is a page token.

Comment: Can you link to where that quote is from? I don’t find it under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens